How do i trick a Powerbank for detection of USB?
I builtd and LED light panel that uses LED strips.   Currently using 2 wire USB cable to power it via Powerbank.
Currently you need to turn the powerbank on and then it provides power to the LED when the switch is pressed down, but it goes to sleep after a bit without use.
From what i have read, USB detection comes from data lines.
How do i incorparate using the data lines so that when i press the switch on the LED, the powerbanks automatically turns on?
Right now im going to just put in a power draw so it never comes off, but i would like to be able to have it turn on right away from USB dection.
THanks!
USB-Type A
the powerbank i used would turn off after use and when i would press the button on the light , the power bank would not turn back on.   Im not trying to keep the load detection on, but the USB detection. (like when you plug it in)

Are you sure it turns off when it sees a real USB device? You also don't say if this is about Type-C or Type-A connectors, in which case the answer may be very different.

I did some testing a while back on a couple Type-A power banks. It’s not data detection, but how much current is drawn and if it’s above a certain threshold. Instead of a static dummy load, you can do a short pulse of dummy current every X seconds where X is just under the timeout period of the bank being below its threshold current and would go back into “sleep”. I found this info in a article/blog somewhere but don’t remember where.

I think it was this: https://blog.zakkemble.net/smart-power-bank-keep-alive/
